# Refresh jQuery dataTable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to refresh my dataTable, but it is not working the way it should.
By calling the method RefreshTable when a button is clicked I get twice the JSON.
The first JSON is the one that should populate the new **REFRESHED** table and I don't know why also the seond DEFAULT JSON is called

```
    var oTable;

    $(document).ready(function () {
      oTable =  $('#table').dataTable({

            "autoWidth":true,
            "scrollY": "500px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging": false,
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "bFilter": false,
            "ajax": "datatables-scripts/table_processing.php"//GET DEFAULT JSON       
        });   
    });

   function resetTable() {
         RefreshTable('#table', 'datatables-scripts/table_processing_refresh.php');//GET NEW JSON

    }

    function RefreshTable(tableId, urlData)
{
  $.getJSON(urlData, null, function( json )
  {
    table = $(tableId).dataTable();
    oSettings = table.fnSettings();

    table.fnClearTable(this);

    for (var i=0; i<json.aaData.length; i++)
    {
      table.oApi._fnAddData(oSettings, json.aaData[i]);
    }

    oSettings.aiDisplay = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster.slice();
    table.fnDraw();
  });
}
```

Comment: `table.fnDraw();` is most likely refreshing the datatable based on its original datasource, ie the one you specified in the datatable initialisation.  This is a strange way to refresh the data - is there a particular reason you're doing it like that?

Comment: I want to populate the table with another data that I get with another MySQL query..

Comment: Could you not do that in the server code, by passing a parameter that tells it which query to run?